# Android expandablelistview textIsSelectable is true for ListView text and how to pass control/focus

Tags: android, expandablelistview, clipboard, samsung-mobile, samsung-touchwiz

In CustomExpandable `ListView` i need to enable ClipBoard functionality for `TextView` which is part Child Item so, i used TextIsSelectable(true), it is working fine in lollipop but, in Kitkat when we longPress on 1st `TextView` clipboard functionality enable but when we longpressed on 2nd `TextView` 1st floating clipboard is not getting disapper means we are gettig multiple floating clipboard in single screen.

How to disappear clipboard onclick of 2nd/any other `TextView`?

Device : Note2/kitkat.

Thanks In Advance